How to fetch and only display the data based on where clause in crystal report
I have sets of data in my database and I want to display the data based on CramNo but upon processing, the report displays all the sets of data and did not fetch it based on the where clause.
Here is my code for selecting the data for the crystal report
    Dim selMainCram As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM CRAMBMain WHERE CramNo = '" & cramNo & "'", jonsqlcon)
    Dim setMainCram As New DataSet
    selMainCram.Fill(setMainCram)

    Dim cryRptB As New ReportDocument
    cryRptB.Load(reportsfolder + "\CRAM\test.rpt")

    Dim crTable As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table
    Dim crTableLogonInfo As CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo
    Dim ConnInfo As New CrystalDecisions.Shared.ConnectionInfo()

            With ConnInfo
                .ServerName = tmpSN
                .DatabaseName = tmpDBN
                .UserID = tmpUID
                .Password = tmpPass
            End With

            For Each crTable In cryRptB.Database.Tables
                crTableLogonInfo = crTable.LogOnInfo
                crTableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo = ConnInfo
                crTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crTableLogonInfo)
            Next

    cryRptB.SetDataSource(setMainCram)

    Me.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRptB
    Me.CrystalReportViewer1.LogOnInfo(0).ConnectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = False
    Me.CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
    Me.Show()


Solved: change the DataSet to DataTable
